# What are demeaning foods to call people?

Tags: pejorative-language

I was debating someone recently, and he started rejecting my view point entirely. He started referring to me as "cupcake", an attempt to insult me, I'm sure. I don't quite understand why, because cupcakes are awesome, but it has been used before, like by [the soldier from Team Fortress 2](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Soldier_voice_commands).

So I was wondering, what are some other foods that could be demeaning to call someone?

Comment: Any food name can be demeaning or not, depending on the context, honey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're a **fruitcake** to ask; you're absolutely **bananas**. I blow a **raspberry** at you.

Comment: *fruit*, *vegetable*, *meathead*, *kraut*, *vanilla*.

Comment: Thanks. And to make it clear, I don't intend to actually use the foods in a reply. You're (not) the liver-worst!

Comment: A cheesy answer, but delivered in a creamy tone.

Comment: Let's not forget the internet's favorite standby: potato.

Answer (score 4):

Giving lists of food related insults (or any other lists) are off topic here, so allow me to answer your implied question about why ' cupcake' might be an insult. Cupcakes are indeed awesomely tasty, but they are delicate, small, light and maybe a bit too sweet. Parents often call their small, children 'cupcake', or a man might say it to a woman he sees as dependent. The insult, if there was one, was trying to put you in the same category as a child or a weak woman.